# How to perform drag and drop in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, mean-stack

Recently i am tying to perform drag and drop in my view and for that i put the following code,

```
  <a data-toggle="pill"   ng-bind="val1.value" draggable="true"></a>
```

With the above code is dragging but not getting replaced.I am using angularjs ,will any code to be implimented in js?Can anyone please help me.Thanks.

Comment: check this link : 
http://angular-dragdrop.github.io/angular-dragdrop/examples/

Comment: Which library do you use for the dragging and dropping?

Comment: I don't think he is.